# How do I get a related element and its children from my XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I have to parse an XML file that is generated by our sales team. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfOrder>
  <Order>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <OrderGuid />
    <BillingAddress>
      <Id>0</Id>
      <FirstName>Harvey</FirstName>
      <LastName>Danger</LastName>
    </BillingAddress>
    <OrderItems>
      <OrderItem>
        <ProductName>Silver Widgets</ProductName>
        <Price>9.99</Price>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
        <OrderDate>7/2/2014 2:05:00 PM</OrderDate>
        <Barcodes>
          <BarCode>
            <string>123CC2D68</string>
          </BarCode>
        </Barcodes>
      </OrderItem>
    </OrderItems>
  </Order>
</ArrayOfOrder>
```

I can list all the elements in the Order Node and I can loop through the children of a particular node. However I have not been able to figure out how to get the Order Id and the corresponding first and last name from the BillingAddress node. I have tried so many different variations of the code below but have not been able to solve this problem:

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(filePath);

    XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList Order = root.SelectNodes("Order");

    string id1 = string.Empty;
    string firstName = string.Empty;
    string lastName = string.Empty;

    foreach(XmlNode order in Order)
    {
        id1 = order["Id"].InnerText;
        //firstName = order["BillingAddress/FirstName"].InnerText;
        //lastName = order["BillingAddress"].InnerText;
        firstName = order["FirstName"].InnerText;
        lastName = order["LastName"].InnerText;

        Console.WriteLine(id1);
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + firstName);
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + lastName);
    }
```

I am trying to accomplish something like this

1
 Harvey
 Danger

So how so I set the first and last name for the corresponding Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some flexibility regarding your approach to working with XML, you should consider moving to **LINQ to XML**. From [LINQ to XML Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) on MSDN:

> **LINQ to XML is an up-to-date, redesigned approach to programming with
>   XML.** It provides the in-memory document modification capabilities of
>   the Document Object Model (DOM), and supports LINQ query expressions.
>   Although these query expressions are syntactically different from
>   XPath, they provide similar functionality.

Also see [LINQ to XML vs. DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387021.aspx) which goes over some of the basic differences between the two APIs.

Here is a complete working example that demonstrates a very basic use of LINQ to XML (`System.Xml.Linq`) on the sample data that you provided. You can do much more after acquiring basic knowledge of LINQ. I think you'll find [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) relatively easy to read and well worth your time. LINQ itself will significantly enhance your productivity when programming with .NET.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace LinqToXmlDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlContent = GetXml();

            XElement arrayOfOrder = XElement.Parse(xmlContent);

            XElement order = arrayOfOrder.Element("Order");
            string orderId = (string)order.Element("Id");            

            XElement billingAddress = order.Element("BillingAddress");
            string firstName = (string)billingAddress.Element("FirstName");
            string lastName = (string)billingAddress.Element("LastName");

            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] [{1}] [{2}]",
                orderId,
                firstName,
                lastName);
        }

        private static String GetXml()
        {
            return
                @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                  <ArrayOfOrder>
                    <Order>
                      <Id>1</Id>
                      <OrderGuid />
                      <BillingAddress>
                        <Id>0</Id>
                        <FirstName>Harvey</FirstName>
                        <LastName>Danger</LastName>
                      </BillingAddress>
                      <OrderItems>
                        <OrderItem>
                          <ProductName>Silver Widgets</ProductName>
                          <Price>9.99</Price>
                          <Quantity>10</Quantity>
                          <OrderDate>7/2/2014 2:05:00 PM</OrderDate>
                          <Barcodes>
                            <BarCode>
                              <string>123CC2D68</string>
                            </BarCode>
                          </Barcodes>
                        </OrderItem>
                      </OrderItems>
                    </Order>
                  </ArrayOfOrder>";
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves the question that I asked so I marked the question as answered. The actual XML that comes in has multiple orders so I am working on figuring out how to loop through the orders with the links you included. Thanks!

Comment: A problem that calls for working with **multiples** and **loops** is exactly what **LINQ** was designed to address! LINQ often makes it much easier to extract what you what from *any* kind of collection (or `IEnumerable`) as an alternative to traditional `for` and `foreach` loops. (Very often though, a very simple `foreach` loop is used at the end *after* you have defined your **LINQ query**.)

Comment: ...For instance, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21806152/1497596) to the question [How to generate array of objects after LINQ to xml in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21798570/1497596). You might try to modify the example I provided to work with your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the XmlNode for The Billing Address and use FirstChild

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.firstchild.aspx

You can also do SelectSingleNode

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx

here is a guide to xPath syntax

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp